# How can I pipe the output of a command to another server?

Tags: php, stream, pipe

I would like to stream the output of a command from one server to a remote server (both linux servers, latest Ubuntu).

In an ideal world, I would like to stream it over https to a webserver that has a php script to receive the input and process it. For the sake of simplicity, let's say the php just outputs the stream to a file on the webserver. In reality it will parse it and put various things in a queue to be dealt with.

I would like it to look something like this (I know this is not valid of course!)

```
tail -f logfile.log | https://myserver.com/receiveLogfile.php
```

receiveLogFile.php would then look something like this:

```
<?php
$stream=fopen( "php://input", "r" );
$out=fopen ("/tmp/receivedLog.log", "a");

// Somehow send $stream to $out?
```

If it's not possible to send it directly to php, then is there a way to send it to a file on the remote server? Ideally without a password (in other words it would need something running on a given port on the remote server to receive the stream and write it to a local file. I'm not sure if something like that already exists or not).

If a password is required, then it would need to be able to be sent non-interactively. For reasons I can't go into here, a keyfile will not work well for my unique situation, so I am hoping to avoid that.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/logstash/ - I believe this will do exactly what you need. This is used in my current job to put out logs in elastic search for Kibana. The request is sent in a JSON string so you may need to change you script to accept this type of data.

Comment: Ideally I'm not looking for a service that goes via a third party, but a way to go directly to my own server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSH to the rescue. You can easily pipe things into a remote server over SSH.
Let's say on server A you have a script like this:

```php
$stream = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
while(!feof($stream)) {
    echo fgets($stream);
}
fclose($stream);
```

From server B you can call the script like this (I just tested it with vagrant):

```bash
echo "my output" | ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222 php test.php
my output
```

Comment: Shame it requires a password/keyfile, but I can still work with it!

Comment: However, based on your answer and way of thinking, some new keywords occurred to me and I found https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/314552 which uses `socat` and `netcat` in place of ssh, and allows me to go to a port, thus no longer needing a password or keyfile!

Comment: @BenHolness If your requests go over an internal network or you have other means of authentication in place - could definitely be a better option :)

Comment: Authentication will happen in-pipe - the first line of the data sent to the php script will have the token.

I do prefer the encryption that SSH provides though, but I really ideally want to avoid having to have a password or keyfile outside of the stream, if I can!